# Размер буфера InputStream

Tags: java, сокет

Есть сокет сервер\клиент на Java данные собираюсь забирать из сокета большими блоками.

```
InStream   = new DataInputStream(this.ClientSocket.getInputStream());
//......
//Размер для примера
byte[] InputData = new byte[8MB];
InStream.readFully(InputData);
```

Вопрос сколько можно копить данных в буфере?(хотелось бы до пары десятков МБ).
Нужно ли что то городить поверх(например BufferedInputStream?)

Или необходимо в обязательном порядке читать меньшими кусками чтоб не переполнить буфер?

```
InStream   = new DataInputStream(this.ClientSocket.getInputStream());
//......
//Размер для примера
byte[] InputData = new byte[8MB];
int ReadedNow = 0;
while(ReadedNow<8MB)
{
  ReadedNow += InStream.read(InputData,ReadedNow,8MB-ReadedNow);
}
```

п.с. код упрощен для демонстрации.